# API printing in terminal but not in HTML template

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am importing news API in my Django project. I can print my data in my terminal however I can't print through my `news.html` file. This could be an issue related to importing the data in HTML.

```
from django.shortcuts import render
    import requests
    def news(request):
        url = ('https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?'
           'sources=bbc-news&'
           'apiKey=647505e4506e425994ac0dc310221d04')
        response = requests.get(url)
        print(response.json())
        news = response.json()
        return render(request,'new/new.html',{'news':news})
```

**base.html**

```
   <html>
       <head>
           <title></title>
       </head>
       <body>
           {% block content %}
           {% endblock %}
       </body>
   </html>
```

**news.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}

<h2>news API</h2>

{% if news %}
    <p><strong>{{ news.title }}</strong><strong>{{ news.name}}</strong> public repositories.</p>
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

**Terminal and API Output**

```
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
November 28, 2018 - 12:31:07
Django version 2.1.3, using settings 'map.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
{'status': 'ok', 'totalResults': 10, 'articles': [{'source': 
{'id': 'bbc-news', 'name': 'BBC News'}, 'author': 'BBC News', 
'title': 'Sri Lanka defence chief held over murders', 
'description': "The country's top officer is in custody, accused of covering up illegal killings in the civil war.", 'url': 'http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-asia-46374111', 'urlToImage': 'https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/news/1024/branded_news/1010/production/_104521140_26571c51-e151-41b9-85a3-d6e441f5262b.jpg', 'publishedAt': '2018-11-28T12:12:05Z', 'content': "Image copyright AFP Image caption Adm Wijeguneratne denies the charges Sri Lanka's top military officer has been remanded in custody, accused of covering up civil war-era murders. Chief of Defence Staff Ravindra Wijeguneratne appeared in court after warrants … [+288 chars]"}, {'source': {'id': 'bbc-news', 'name': 'BBC News'}, 'author': 'BBC News', 'title': 'Flash-flooding causes chaos in Sydney', 'description': "Emergency crews respond to hundreds of calls on the city's wettest November day since 1984.", 'url': 'http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-australia-46366961', 'urlToImage': 'https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/images/ic/1024x576/p06t1d6h.jpg', 'publishedAt': '2018-11-28T11:58:49Z', 'content': 'Media caption People in vehicles were among those caught up in the floods Sydney has been deluged by the heaviest November rain it has experienced in decades, causing flash-flooding, traffic chaos and power cuts. Heavy rain fell throughout Wednesday, the city… [+2282 chars]'}, {'source': {'id': 'bbc-news', 'name': 'BBC News'}, 'author': 'BBC News', 'title': "Rapist 'gets chance to see victim's child'", 'description': 'Sammy Woodhouse calls for a law change after rapist Arshid Hussain is given the chance to see his son.', 'url': 'http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-england-south-yorkshire-46368991', 'urlToImage': 'https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/news/1024/branded_news/12C94/production/_95184967_jessica.jpg', 'publishedAt': '2018-11-28T09:38:07Z', 'content': "Image caption Sammy Woodhouse's son was conceived when she was raped by Arshid Hussain A child exploitation scandal victim has called for a law change amid claims a man who raped her has been invited to play a role in her son's life. Arshid Hussain, who was j… [+2543 chars]"}, {'source': {'id': 'bbc-news', 'name': 'BBC News'}, 'author': 'BBC News', 'title': 'China chemical plant explosion kills 22', 'description': 'Initial reports say a vehicle carrying chemicals exploded while waiting to enter the north China plant.', 'url': 'http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-asia-46369041', 'urlToImage': 'https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/news/1024/branded_news/2E1A/production/_104520811_mediaitem104520808.jpg', 'publishedAt': '2018-11-28T08:03:12Z', 'content': 'Image copyright AFP Image caption A line of burnt out vehicles could be seen outside the chemical plant At least 22 people have died and 22 more were injured in a blast outside a chemical factory in northern China. A vehicle carrying chemicals exploded while … [+1252 chars]'}, {'source': {'id': 'bbc-news', 'name': 'BBC News'}, 'author': 'BBC News', 'title': 'Thousands told to flee Australia bushfire', 'description': 'Queensland\'s fire danger warning has been raised to "catastrophic" for the first time.', 'url': 'http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-australia-46366964', 'urlToImage': 'https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/news/1024/branded_news/8977/production/_104519153_1ccd493b-4500-4d8d-9e6c-f32ba036dd3e.jpg', 'publishedAt': '2018-11-28T07:01:41Z', 'content': 'Image copyright EPA Image caption More than 130 bushfires are burning across Queensland, officials say Thousands of Australians have been told to evacuate their homes as a powerful bushfire threatens properties in Queensland. It follows the raising of the sta… [+974 chars]'}, {'source': {'id': 'bbc-news', 'name': 'BBC News'}, 'author': 'BBC News', 'title': "Chinese scientist defends 'gene-editing'", 'description': "He Jiankui shocked the world by claiming he had created the world's first genetically edited children.", 'url': 'http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-asia-china-46368731', 'urlToImage': 'https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/news/1024/branded_news/7A23/production/_97176213_breaking_news_bigger.png', 'publishedAt': '2018-11-28T06:00:22Z', 'content': 'A Chinese scientist who claims to have created the world\'s first genetically edited babies has defended his work. Speaking at a genome summit in Hong Kong, He Jiankui, an associate professor at a Shenzhen university, said he was "proud" of his work. He said "… [+335 chars]'}, {'source': {'id': 'bbc-news', 'name': 'BBC News'}, 'author': 'BBC News', 'title': 'Republican wins Mississippi Senate seat', 'description': "Cindy Hyde-Smith wins Mississippi's Senate race in a vote overshadowed by racial acrimony.", 'url': 'http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-us-canada-46361369', 'urlToImage': 'https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/news/1024/branded_news/3A2B/production/_104519841_050855280.jpg', 'publishedAt': '2018-11-28T04:19:15Z', 'content': "Image copyright Reuters Image caption In her victory speech, Cindy Hyde-Smith promised to represent all Mississippians Republican Cindy Hyde-Smith has won Mississippi's racially charged Senate election, beating a challenge from the black Democrat, Mike Espy. … [+4327 chars]"}, {'source': {'id': 'bbc-news', 'name': 'BBC News'}, 'author': 'BBC News', 'title': "Lion Air should 'improve safety culture'", 'description': 'Indonesian authorities release a preliminary report into a crash in October that killed 189 people.', 'url': 'http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-asia-46121127', 'urlToImage': 'https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/news/1024/branded_news/1762F/production/_104519759_45e74e27-2dc6-45dc-bded-405c057702f5.jpg', 'publishedAt': '2018-11-28T04:10:45Z', 'content': "Image copyright Reuters Image caption The families of the victims visited the site of the crash to pay tribute Indonesian authorities have recommended that budget airline Lion Air improve its safety culture, in a preliminary report into last month's deadly cr… [+1725 chars]"}, {'source': {'id': 'bbc-news', 'name': 'BBC News'}, 'author': 'BBC News', 'title': "Trump 'may cancel Putin talks over Ukraine'", 'description': '"I don\'t like the aggression," the US leader says after Russia seizes Ukrainian boats off Crimea.', 'url': 'http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-europe-46367191', 'urlToImage': 'https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/news/1024/branded_news/0C77/production/_104519130_050842389.jpg', 'publishedAt': '2018-11-28T01:08:30Z', 'content': 'Image copyright AFP Image caption Some of the detained Ukrainians have appeared in court in Crimea US President Donald Trump says he may cancel a meeting with Russian President Vladimir Putin following a maritime clash between Russia and Ukraine. Mr Trump tol… [+4595 chars]'}, {'source': {'id': 'bbc-news', 'name': 'BBC News'}, 'author': 'BBC News', 'title': 'Wandering dog home after 2,200-mile adventure', 'description': "Sinatra the husky was found in Florida 18 months after vanishing in New York. Here's how he got home.", 'url': 'http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-us-canada-46353240', 'urlToImage': 'https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/news/1024/branded_news/D49E/production/_104503445_p06t0kn9.jpg', 'publishedAt': '2018-11-27T21:47:59Z', 'content': "Video Sinatra the husky was found in Florida 18 months after vanishing in New York. Here's the remarkable story of how he got home."}]}
 [28/Nov/2018 12:31:12] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 155
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data you get from that API doesn't have title or name as attributes at the top level. Rather, they are inside the articles element, which itself is a list.

```
{% for article in news.articles %}
    <p><strong>{{ article.title }}</strong><strong>{{ article.source.name }}</strong> public repositories.</p>
{% endif %}
```